# Can I say: I have not gone to the cinema for a long time

Tags: present-perfect, past-participles

Joe asks me: "Do you often go to the cinema?"

I reply: "No, **I have not been** to the cinema for a long time"

This is correct.

But can I say:

> "I **have not gone** to the cinema for a long time"

Comment: As long as you're not standing right in front of the Cineplex *gone* is fine to me.

Comment: The correct way to reply would be, "I have not gone to the cinema in a long time".

Comment: downvotes for no valid reason? Not fair. +1 as it makes a *valid question*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I **have not gone** to the cinema in a long time
>   I **have not been** to the cinema in a long time
>   I **have not seen** a movie in a theatre for a long time

All have basically the same meaning that you have not seen a movie, eating popcorn and drinking soda, in a building for **a while**.

The **present perfect** is used since it was a situation which **began in the past and continues**

Comment: I agree with Peter but since he has offered alternative phrasing I would like to just point out that most *conversational* English speakers will tend to use contractions ("haven't" -vs- "have not") and also frequently use "the movies" instead of "the cinema". Thus: "**I haven't been to the movies in a long time.**" would also be an acceptable *conversational* English phrasing.

Comment: @O.M.Y. +1 I was staying in line with the OP not using contractions

Comment: Understood, I just think it is helpful to occasionally provide some informal / conversational usage versus "stiff" formal usage so that ELL's can recognize when spoken English may be different from the written form.

Answer (score 3):

(Please note: This answer has an American English bias.)

A natural response would be

> No, I haven't been in a long time.

You could also use *gone*.

Notice: *in a long time*. This seems more likely here, although there's nothing wrong with *for a long time*.

I wouldn't repeat *cinema* in my response. But if I wanted to include the destination in my response, I would rarely say *cinema* (which is more characteristic of British English).

In the US, *movie theater* is probably more used more often than *cinema*. But in American English we would most likely say

> No. I haven't gone to *the movies* in a long time.

*The movies* is the usual expression used in the US to mean *cinema*. See [Why do you say "to the movies"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/8377/why-do-you-say-to-the-movies)

and

["Movies" vs. "Cinema" vs. "Theater" -- what's the difference?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21694/movies-vs-cinema-vs-theater-whats-the-difference).